# Interpreting R Bootstrapping Output: Confidence Intervals

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to understand bootstrapping in R using the Boot package. I am trying to do a simple spearman rank correlation. I have some code based on a tutorial I found online but am having some issues interpreting the output. The code is below:

*Note: these data are just random numbers I used to help me learn how to run the boot function. They do not represent anything.

```
test_a=data.frame(v1 = c(1,5,8,3,2,9,5,10,3,5), v2 = c(3,4,7,2,1,10,3,8,8,2))

attach(test_a)
cor.test(v1, v2, method = "spearman")

function_2 = function(test_a, i) {
  d2 = test_a[i,]
  return(cor(d2$v1, d2$v2, method="spearman"))
}

set.seed(1)
test_boot = boot(test_a, function_2, R=1000)
test_boot
```

I get the following output:

```
boot(data = test_a, statistic = function_2, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
     original      bias    std. error
t1* 0.6397639 -0.04253283   0.2547429
```

Which all makes sense to me. But I guess my confusion is with the boot.ci function

```
ci = boot.ci(test_boot, conf=0.95)
```

I get the following output:

```
> ci
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = test_boot, conf = 0.95)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 0.1830,  1.1816 )   ( 0.3173,  1.2987 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   (-0.0192,  0.9622 )   (-0.1440,  0.9497 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

And this is where I am a bit lost. I can't really find a source that explains in layman's terms in the context of a correlation coefficient, because obviously you cannot have a correlation > 1.0, yet this spits out a confidence interval (at least with two methods) that goes above 1. The sources that discuss these different confidence intervals frankly have been a bit confusing. Is there any one of these that is better for certain parameters than others? It is also possible I am completely misinterpreting what I am doing as well.

I also include the results of plot(test_boot) for your reference.

[image: plot(test_boot)]

The eventual goal (with actual data) once I am more confident in running and interpreting results of bootstrapping would be to run tests for trends with time (Mann-Kendall test for trends and Thiel-Sen Slope Estimator, I cannot use parametric statistics with my data :/) and compare my observed dataset with bootstrapped samples.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The two top intervals are normal theory intervals.  They use the bootstrap to calculate the standard error and then make symmetric intervals that may or may not respect the bounds of the statistic.  The bottom two intervals are percentile intervals (the first is a raw percentile interval and the second is a bias-corrected, accelerated interval).  These identify particular values of the bootstrap statistics that define the CI.  As such, they will always respect the theoretical bounds of the statistic being bootstrapped.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveArmstrong, I appreciate your time to reply.

That is about what I was expecting. In that case then, what is the common interval to report? It seems like I would report the BCa one?

Comment: @nsg794 I think you're right, the BCa intervals are most likely to give the correct coverage.

Comment: thank you so much! I appreciate your help!